# SVG draw elements between animation points

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-animate

I would like to draw elements between the animation. I mean pixel by pixel stars on the path. How can i draw all the stars? I would like to draw it after the animation is runing like when the snail goes he let a streak behind him.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110"
      stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" 
      fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>

  <polygon points="10,0.1 4,19.8 19.0,7.8 1.0,7.8 16.0,19.8" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2;fill-rule:evenodd;" >
    
    <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

**EDIT:** This post marked to "already answered" so why it is different? I dont want to change the stroke i want to make more elements to my svg.